# How can I have my app save data to Kindle Fire storage?

Tags: android, sd-card, kindle-fire

Currently, I'm working on an app that downloads and saves files to /sdcard. But a function I have that detects current sd card status says that no sd card was detected when I run it on the Kindle Fire emulator. My question is: How can I save these files to the Kindle Fire's storage, since it doesn't seem to have an /sdcard directory to save to?

Comment: `/sdcard` has been wrong for about two years. Please use the proper methods on the `Environment` class to gain access to external storage.

Comment: Thanks. Still doesn't solve my problem though. I need a way to save to the Kindle Fire's storage. Using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() still tries to open /mnt/sdcard

Comment: `/mnt/sdcard` is correct on the Kindle Fire.

Comment: I'm using the emulator. My other android emulators have sdcard access. A call to Environment.getExternalStorageState() always returns MEDIA_REMOVED, which means there's no external storage detected.

Comment: And when I try to save the file without checking the external storage state, it always throws a FileNotFoundException with permission denied when trying to save the file.

Comment: Your problem is with your emulator, then. An actual Kindle Fire reports the state as mounted, and allows you to write to it.

Comment: It doesn't make sense though. I have a virtual SD card for the emulator. And in the "Hardware" field of the AVD settings, it lists the emulator as having SD card support.